# Android: Have two drawer layout (right and left) with two different transition

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have two drawer layout, one from right to left, and another one from left to right. They work perfectly fine, but both of them open/close with the same transition.

Can I have two different transition?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? That is, how do you want them to transition?

Comment: Hi Mike, I would like have two different transition: the first one must have default transition, and with the second one I would have "main activity layout" that move to right with setX(). I have already implement this transition (mainActivityLayout.setX() ), but I think that's impossibile having two drawer having two different transiton.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. I assume you're using a `DrawerListener` - maybe an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` - to achieve the content move. In the `onDrawerSlide()` method, the `View` parameter is the drawer `View` that's currently sliding. Just check if that's your second drawer, and if it is, do the `setX()` call.

Comment: Thanks mike! Meanwhile I tried another solution: delete drawer layout on the left, and i put just one simple layout behind main_activity layout (having framelayout as parent), so when i press the button main_activity layout slide on the left, showing the layout behind (before left_drawer_layout). 

I think is a better solution having a layout with 100% width, and transitction effect more appreciable. 

Thanks again!